# Line 253 Left side of assignment operator must be variable or property. (Action Script)

Tags: actionscript-2

For some reason i'm getting this error

```
  Line 253 Left side of assignment operator must be variable or property.
```

The problem lays in here on line 253

```
   function handler()
    {
        var _loc2;
        for (var _loc4 in _activeBalloons)
        {
            _loc2 = _activeBalloons[_loc4];
            if (_loc2.__get__counter() >= _loc2.__get__duration())
            {
                if (_loc2 instanceof com.clubpenguin.ui.balloons.TextBalloon)
                {
                    var _loc3 = (com.clubpenguin.ui.balloons.TextBalloon)(_loc2);
                    if (!_loc3.isDone())
                    {
                        _loc3.showNextPart();
                        continue;
                    } // end if
                } // end if
                _loc2.hide();
                this.deactivate(_loc2);
            } // end if
            _loc2.__set__counter(++_loc2.__get__counter());
        } // end of for...in
    } // End of the function
```

Line 253

`_loc2.__set__counter(++_loc2.__get__counter());`

I'm not sure what's wrong but I need help

Comment: try `_loc2.__set__counter(_loc2.__get__counter() + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

you can not increment a value (which is your function return) using ++ operator.